# (Android) How to match VideoView's content depend on its size

Tags: android, android-videoview

I tried any way to do the VideoView's content match with it. But the seem it's impossible. Could I resize content video match with VideoView size. I need any help! Thanks for helping!

[landscape image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4OsG.jpg)

[portrait image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koYQ3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your code VideView

```
public void resizeVideo(int width, int height) {
getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
requestLayout();
invalidate(); 
}
```